# Typing math shortcuts is delayed on LyX

Tags: math-mode, lyx, shortcut

Recently I installed LyX version 2.3.7 on my Windows PC. Everything is working just fine, except for the fact that when I enter math mode (CTRL + m) and I want to enter a quick command such as `\epsilon`, I have to wait like 2-3 seconds until the dropdown list appears, and only then can I hit the Enter button to enter the shortcut. My big problem is that as long as the list doesn't appear it takes a really long time for me to write math expressions and it's really frustrating.

[image: DropDownList]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! I think your question was good, and you included a very helpful screenshot to know exactly what was going on. Well done! Although I disagree, some voted to mark your question as off-topic, but please don't be discouraged from asking LyX questions here again. They're generally on topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the dropdown list delay in toos->preferences->editing->input completion->general->popup delay.